# Idiomatic Haskell code to simplify recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, idioms

I need to compute `foo n = maximumBy (comparing p) [1..n]`, where `p :: Int -> Int` is slow. But I know that `p n < n` for all `n > 0` and want to use this fact to speed up this computation the following way: I compute `p x` for `x` beginning with `n` down to `1`, memorizing the current maximum. Once I reach an `x` less or equal to the current maximum, I know that this maximum must be the global one and I am done.

So my attempt looks like this:

```
foo n = go (0, 0) n where
    go (c, _) 1 = c
    go (c, c') !x = if c' >= x then c else go (c2, c'2) (x-1) where
        x' = p x
        (c2, c'2) = if c' >= x' then (c, c') else (x, x')
```

This works, but does not look very idiomatic. So I am looking for a more elegant solution. Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to reduce the use of if ... then ... else
Another trick is to give a number to your variable, it allow you to remember the starting case **var0** and for the other recursive call you can then use a nicer **var**
Last note, you have some **if** returning the same value after a predicate of the same form and sharing the same environment then may be you can group them together.

```
foo n0 = go (0, 0) n0
  where
    go (x, y) n
        | (n  == 1) || (y >= n) = x
        | y < (p n) = go (n, (p n)) (n-1)
        | otherwise = go (x, y) (n-1)
```

---

Rewriting taking into account comment,

```
foo n0 = go 0 0 n0
  where
    go x y n
        | (n  == 1) || (y >= n) = x
        | pn > y                = go n pn (n-1)
        | otherwise             = go x y (n-1)
          where
            pn = p n
```

Comment: Get rid of the pair, make it `go x y n ...`, and I would bind `p n` to a name (don't even give the compiler a chance to recompute it), otherwise that's what I'd do. Simple, clear, efficient.

Comment: Thanks, replace the pair as you suggested it's definitely better. Anyway, I must admit I've hesitate about a use of a let ... in binding as I really doesn't know if in my second pattern matching, the (p n) will be compute twice or not. If I have to justify my code, I would argue that Haskell is lazy by nature, this mean it evaluation strategy is call-by-need and by definition "Call-by-need is a memoized version of call-by-name", then it should be ok, no ?. As it's true that using a let in binding as you suggested do not let any place for doubt, I've added your suggestion below mine.

Comment: I'd use a `where`. `go x y n | n == 1 || n <= y = x | pn > y = go n pn (n-1) | otherwise = go x y (n-1) where pn = p n`.

Comment: Mind if I have a go at it?

Comment: absolutely not, just do it

Comment: Regarding the question whether `p n` would be recomputed if it isn't bound to a name; with optimisations, probably not. But to be sure one would need to look at the core. However, I've learned to never blindly trust a compiler, and introducing a local binding is less work than looking at the core, and does the intended thing as long as the compiler is even quarter-sane, so I do that in such situations.

Comment: This looks indeed more beautiful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so let me see if I wrapped my brain around this correctly... You're saying that `p n < n` for all interesting `n`. And you want to compute `p x` for `x = n to 1`, until `x` becomes less than the largest `p x` seen so far?

Well, it looks like you could compute all the `p x` as a lazy list. Now the problem is reduced to scanning this list until you find what you're looking for. I would suggest `takeWhile`, except we also need to *fold* the list to find the current maximum. Hmm, perhaps we can pair each value with the running maximum?

Something like

```
foo n =
  let
    ps = [ p x | x <- [n, n-1 .. 1] ]
    qs = fold (\ px' (px, maxPX) -> (px', maxPX `max` px') ) ps
  in last . takeWhile (\ (px, maxPX) -> px >= maxPX) qs
```

or similar?